# How to send data as object in angularjs DELETE request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am trying to send the ID of element to nodejs api using angularjs $resource delete method, The value is sending as parameter value how can I send that value as a body parameter?

my code is like this

In angularjs

```
    var ids = {
        delId : row._id
    }
    $resource('/deleteUser').delete(ids,function(data){
        alert(data)
    });
```

In nodejs

```
app.delete('/deleteUser', function(req, res) {
    console.log('called');
    var resp = {
        success : true,
        id : req.body.id
        }
    console.log(req)
    res.json(resp)
});
```

But Its sending only success in the response ignoring id value, How can it be done?

Comment: You should definitely have a `/user/:id` route instead.

Comment: But my requirement is data shouldn't be in url parameters it should be send as body object just like sending data in post method

Comment: @NagababjiBusam according to [specs](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.7) the id of the resource to DELETE must be in the URI.

Comment: HI ~ if you don't mind modify the angular resource source code ~ Edit the angular-resource.js file "var hasBody = /^(POST|PUT|PATCH)$/i.test(action.method);" change to "var hasBody = /^(POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE)$/i.test(action.method);" I think that is the best easy way .

Comment: I have changed in resource.js file that hasBody code In browser its showing the id was send in request pay load but in backed its not showing any data in body object.

For DELETE request
body: {},

For POST request
body: 
   { name: 'hgasfd',
     phone: '8726342322',
     gender: 'female',
     email: 'ags@kja.asd' },

Comment: You have to add content-type header to make body parser work $resource('/deleteUser',{},{
                delete:{
                    method: 'DELETE',
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
                }
            }).delete({"_ids":ids},function(data){
                // alert(data)
            });

Answer (score 0):

here is what I would do for the angular part:

```
  angular.module('yourModule').factory('cmsUser', function($http) {

  var cmsUser = {};

  cmsUser.Delete = function(user) {
    return $http.delete("your url/", user);
  };

  return cmsUser;
});

angular.module('yourModule').factory('userService', function(cmsUser, $q) {

  var userService = {};

  userService.Delete = function(user) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    cmsUser.Delete(user)
      .success(function(data, status, config, headers) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
      })
      .error(function(data, status, config, headers) {
        deferred.reject(data);
      });

    return deferred.promise;
  };

  return userService;
});

angular.module('yourModule').Controller('YourController', function(userService) {

  var vm = this;

  vm.Delete = function(user) {
    userService.Delete(user)
      .then(function() {
        // this is the sucess
        console.log("user deleted");
      }, function(reason) {
        // this is the error
        console.log(reason.message);
      });
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your code but you are using http delete request, But I need $resource delete request